# OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException - C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

A text has to be entered in a Textbox, a list auto-extends, and I need to select the first item. But it fails due to the exception; OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException. I tried using wait.Until(), but facing the same error.

[image: Screenshot]

```
try
{
     IWebElement cityList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("value"));
     MouseClick(driver, cityList);
}
catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException ex)
{
     IWebElement cityList = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("value"));
     MouseClick(driver, cityList);
}
```

**Edit**

HTML code:

```
<input name="ctl00$cphmain$txtCity" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_cphmain_txtCity" class="mandsearchtxtbox" onkeypress="javascript:return ValidateInputAlphabeticValuesOnly(event);" onblur="javascript:return checkItemMsg(this)" style="width:180px;" autocomplete="off">
<div class="AutoExtenderHighlight">AMANDOLUWA</div>
```

Code with wait.Until()

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
        {
            try
            {
                return d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='citydiv']/div"));
                MouseClick(driver, driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='citydiv']/div")));
            }
            catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException ex)
            {
                return null;
                MouseClick(driver, driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='citydiv']/div")));
            }
        });
```

**Edit 2**

HTML code for WebDriverException(Button)

[image: HTML code]

Comment: Please add the code you have tried as well as the relevant html.

Comment: Added the html and tried code. I am not sure if wait.until() code is correct or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the html you posted the id is `ctl00_cphmain_txtCity`, not `citydiv`.

Your `wait.Until` implementation will return `IWebElement` or `null`, it will never reach to the `MouseClick` method. It will also check if the element exists, not visible.

You can use the built in [expected conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) class

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphmain_txtCity']/div")));
element.Click();
```

If you want your own implementation you can do something like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement option = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    try
    {
        IWebElement element = d.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphmain_txtCity']/div"));
        if (element.Displayed)
        {
            return element;
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ) { }
    catch (StaleElementReferenceException) { }

    return null;
});

option.Click();
```

Although I commander you use the built in functionality.

Comment: Also,  ctl00_cphmain_txtCity is the id for the Textbox, whereas citydiv is the id for the auto-extender list. So, the latter id is used.

Comment: Another doubt regarding the wait. What if timeout exception is thrown after 10seconds. It won't enter the try block if it fails due to timeout.

Comment: @testingqwerty A `TimeoutException` will be thrown only on the `wait.Until`, witch is outside the `try catch` block anyway. The `FindElement` method will throw only `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: I am talking about the exception been thrown on 'wait.Until' only

Comment: @testingqwerty If you want to catch `TimeoutException` you can put it inside `try catch` block as well `IWebElement option; try { option = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => {...}); } catch (TimeoutException ex){ }`

Comment: As per the code mentioned in the Answer, I am facing `WebDriverTimeoutException`, also on putting the code in `try-catch` block, it is failing.

Comment: @testingqwerty Can you share your current code? And can you share the site link?

Comment: The link is hosted on local server.

Comment: @testingqwerty The `try catch` block will prevent the test to fail on this exception, but it still means the element wasn't located. You can't click on it. Check if its inside `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: The element is not in `<iframe>` tag. Please refer the question (Edit 2) for the HTML code.

Comment: @testingqwerty Is this html is for the dropdown choices or for something else?

Comment: Drop down is working. But for another button click, I was facing same error. For that I got `WebDriverTimeoutException`. HTML code is for that element.

Comment: @testingqwerty In that case you should post new question with your code and html (as text, not picture). The comments are not meant to answer new questions.